# Making beautiful transitions at PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to make custom transition with in PageViewController: while user moves to next slide (scroll) then background image slowly dissolves into another image.

Such effect have Apple Weather (except there is background video).

What I've done:

- I've made UIViewContoller with background image (that image I need to change).
- I've placed ContainerView in that UIViewController, that ContainerView have embed PageViewController. UIViewController -> ContainerView -> PageViewController

At that point I'm stuck, i have working PageViewController with shared background image (from top UIViewController), but I have no idea where to go next.

Now I can catch page changing with my delegate (main ViewContoller):

```
func pageChanged(currentPage: Int) {}
```

And default delegate method (PageViewContoller) (I have 2 slides, don't know how to do it better):

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    let prevController = previousViewControllers as [ContentViewController]
    if completed {
        if prevController[0].index == 0 {
            delegate.pageChanged(1)
        } else {
            delegate.pageChanged(2)
        }
    }
}
```

But it is instant function, I can't do here slowly animation in dependency of user slowly swipes :).

Comment: It sounds like you actually need to use a `UICollectionView`. From this you can get access to the `scrollView` delegates, and based on the position you can start to do your image transition.

Comment: Eh… it will be much more complex that PageViewContoller as I think :(. Now i'm thinking about tricks with swipe gesture recognizer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I totally agree with Vasily. You need to use a `UICollectionView` and use `self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;`. Then you can control perfectly the scrollview contentOffset via `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
optional func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

The code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var currentX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    var ratio = currentX / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    var previousPageIndex = floor(ratio)
    var nextPageIndex = ceil(ratio)
    ratio = ratio - previousPageIndex

}
```

For instance, if the `ratio` is 0.33, the transition is 33% between the page `previousPageIndex` and the page `nextPageIndex`. You can use this values for set your alpha values in your `UIImageView`s:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var currentX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    var ratio = currentX / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    var previousPageIndex = floor(ratio)
    var nextPageIndex = ceil(ratio)
    ratio = ratio - previousPageIndex

    fromImageView.alpha = 1.0 - ratio;
    toImageView.alpha = ratio;

}
```

The `PageViewController` doesn't allow you control scrolling itself. The transition is a discrete event here. The swipe gesture is a discrete event too and you can add a smooth effect with it. The pan gesture can help you but the code will be more complex and dirty.

Comment: There is no need to avoid using the UIPageViewController. You can access its scroll view per my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer directs you to use a `UICollectionViewController` rather than a `UIPageViewController` so you can access the UIScrollView, set it's delegate and monitor the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Rather than avoiding using the page view controller, you can access its scroll view like this:

```
    let scrollView = self.view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as? UIScrollView
```

You can then set the delegate for the scrollView and enjoy access to the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and others. Implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in combination with the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocol should provide you with enough state information to accomplish your needs.

Comment: Good call! I knew deep down inside I didn't really need to rewrite all my tried & tested page view controller code.