# swift UIPageViewController with cross dissolve animation

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I searched for long time and came to know that we cannot have any other animation except curl and scroll, in UIPageViewController.

I need to use cross dissolve instead of scroll or page curl, but it is not accepting anything other than scroll and page curl.

```
let vc = IntroPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I use .crossDissolve instead of .scroll or .pageCurl.

I tried in IntroPageViewController

```
let nxtVc = pendingViewControllers.first as! IntroSinglePageViewController
nxtVc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration:1,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: { }, completion: nil)
```

it worked but now I have both animations, scroll and crossDissolve.
How can I get rid of scroll animation here.

Comment: have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397251/making-beautiful-transitions-at-pageviewcontroller

Comment: yes bro, but I don't want to use UICollectionView, is there anything we can do with UIPageViewController?